# How to create a Symbolic link to PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

I'm using Laravel. Whenever I need to run the tests I have to execute PHPUnit in the following directory:

```
vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit
```

How can I create a symlink to the file above so that I don't have to type in the full path to phpunit every time ?

I tried the following command but didn't work:

```
ln -s vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit mysym
```

For some reason, it says 'Command Not Found' when I try to execute the Symlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create a symlink to the file above so that I don't have to type in the full path to phpunit every time ?

You don't do any symlinks. Instead you need to add that path to your `$PATH` variable. Additionally, you should use `vendor/bin` folder, not the package's folders directly.

So in your shell do:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/you/project/vendor/bin/
```

You can add that to your `.bashrc` as well.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for the answer. Please note that running phpunit from my /var/www folder executes another phpunit binary which doesn't work with laravel. I tried to add vendor/bin/phpunit folder to PATH variables but didnt help. I tried to purge the phpunit which I have installed through apt-get (the one which don't work as supposed to do) but now when I run phpunit from my www folder it says phpunit is not installed although running the full path works. Or is a server reboot is required for the path variable to take effect ? Thanks

Comment: Hi Marcin, Thanks for the answer. That was just due to typo in the path variable.

Answer (score 1):

composer.json has an option to set where command files are placed:

```
"bin-dir": "vendor/bin",
```

It can be set to just "bin" - and so it, and the other runnable files that are included by Composer would be there, for example `bin/phpunit`.

See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md

There is also another option available - the [composer scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#writing-custom-commands), which is also used to run the "post-install-cmd" &  "post-update-cmd", but you can put your own command in there.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "phpunit -v --debug",
    "behat": "behat",
    "post-install-cmd": [
    ... rest of composer.json
```

Here, if I type `composer test`, it will run PHPunit with the command line given.