# How do I make a composer.json script accept flags

Tags: composer-php

I can't add a `--filter` argument to my `composer.json` script.

I've been reading up [the docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have the following script in my `composer.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "test": [
        ".\\vendor\\bin\\phpunit"
    ]
},
```

But I can't send any `--filters` with it like:

```
$ composer test --filter pigeon_ringnumber_cant_be_more_then_9_chars_for_BE_NL_ESP
```

This outputs the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]  
  The "--filter" option does not exist.
```

Any idea how I can make the script accept the `--filter` argument?

I want to be able to run it quicker then always typing

```
.\\vendor\\bin\\phpunit
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you pass an argument to a composer script from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910354/how-do-you-pass-an-argument-to-a-composer-script-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Oh it's called an 'Argument', not a 'flag', that's why I wasn't getting decent search results on here and google. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! A flag has no value! Flags are either set or not set. Arguments or parameters can have values :-)

Comment: Alright thanks! I updated my original question with the solution I found in your link! Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key here is reading carefully the docs. In docs there is:

> Similar to the run-script command you can give additional arguments to scripts, e.g. composer test -- --filter  will pass --filter  along to the phpunit script.

So to pass `--filter pigeon_ringnumber_cant_be_more_then_9_chars_for_BE_NL_ESP` you should in fact run:

```
composer test -- --filter pigeon_ringnumber_cant_be_more_then_9_chars_for_BE_NL_ESP
```

so you should use here additional `--` before specifying arguments that you want to pass.

Of course in this case the solution you search might be much simpler. You could just consider [creating symbolic link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46837745/how-to-create-a-symbolic-link-to-phpunit) to do this.